# Are there any SSIS plugins that convert nondelimited files to delimited files?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Are there any plugins for SSIS (or external tools) that will convert a datasource that is formatted like an invoice and convert it into a delimited format? You might have a row indicating the customer, then an order description line, then lines for each item ordered, and a summery at the end, followed by another invoice.

I have a vague memory of doing this at a prior employer maybe 10 years ago. You could load the file into the tool and define patterns it could use to parse out the rows and columns. This could be used as a datasource int he ETL tool. I thought we were using SSIS at that point, but I can't find a way to do this in SSIS (besides writing my own code in c# which is not my strong suit).

Comment: Before answering, I will politefully suggest that investing in things which are not your strong suit is an excellent way to make yourself invaluable, and a custom C# solution of this nature seems like a pretty nice Hello World introduction to the world of file streaming, pattern matching, and creating machine-friendly consumable output.

Comment: Hello Kyle! That is an excellent suggestion. I am actually already doing those types of things. I am learning c# and have been allowed to work on a few simple web services. However, I know that I cannot do something at this level in the time frame of the project. I mentioned this tool that I remember using to my boss, and was asked to see if I could dig it up, or a similar tool. They will then evaluate the cost of purchasing the tool vs increasing the time frame of the project to allow for a custom written solution.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I don't think there are any off-the-shelf tools that provide a useful output to you, so your cost evaluation should be how much will it cost to post this task on a site like eLance (estimate: $100?) versus rolling your own. If you do roll your own, check out Sprache, it's a great custom text parser with a nice elegant method for breaking down your file into its component parts.

Comment: 10 years ago there was one, because I used it. But for the life of me I cannot remember what is what called. We were also transitioning ETL tools, so I am not even 100% sure it was an SSIS plug in.